# Man page for golang?

Tags: go, manpage

Though `go help` is useful, but still it's not as expressive as man pages.

So, any way to get man page for go binaries on unix based systems?

If not, why such a feature hasn't been done since golang is so popular nowadays?

Comment: Man pages on Windows?

Comment: @Volker The question said `unix` based systems.

Comment: As man page for `g++` exists why not one for `go`?

Comment: The `go help` text changes dynamically now for many commands depending on whether or not you're in a module package. It might be cumbersome to have two separate manpages for each command and always have to add a suffix or something in order to look up the one you want.

Comment: It is shocking to find that go has no man page. I did `man go` today in FreeBSD to check about the available options for build and I thought that there was something wrong with the man pages in my system.

Answer (score 7):

You have an alternative with **goman**, [presented here](https://appliedgo.net/goman/)

See the GitHub project [christophberger/goman](https://github.com/christophberger/goman): that is not for Go itself, but could be adapted to generate the man page for Go.

Otherwise... [go issue 101](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/101) is one of the oldest issues out there (2009), and still opened!
It was supposed to be fixed by an official goman command (see [CL 5700081](https://codereview.appspot.com/5700081/)), but that never was completed.

Comment: I installed it, by `go get -u github.com/christophberger/goman`, and add the `main () {..}` part into `.bashrc`, but when execute command `goman` it says `No command 'goman' found`.

Comment: @EricWang Is your $GOPATH/bin part of your PATH? Do you see goman in $GOPATH/bin?

Comment: It's missing, I just added it, and now could found command `goman`, and seems need to get the source code of those binaries to get result from `goman xxx`?

Comment: And seems it simple print content of README file, e.g `goman goman`, and `goman go` can't find doc, since there is no README file for it. So, seems it's not a perfect alternate for the typical man page.

Comment: @EricWang First: has goman been compiled and installed as a result of the go get -u? "could found command goman" means either it was not, or the PATH does not reference GOPATH/bin. Or you did not exported the new PATH.

Comment: @EricWang That is what I meant with "that is not for Go itself": not an ideal solution, just an idea to be adapted.

Comment: @EricWang The sources in https://codereview.appspot.com/5700081/ are more fit for Go commands themselves... but was never completed.

Comment: I see, I found a solution for ubuntu, please check the answer I just added.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu, I found this solution: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu

---

### Example - ubuntu 16.04 & golang 1.10 *(2018-04)*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```

Then man pages are available.

e.g

```
man go
man go-get    # man page for `go get` sub command,
man gofmt
```

Tips:

- Newest version of golang might can't be installed via the method above *(it has some kind of delay I think)*.
  My solution is to install the newest/desired version of golang via download manually, and make sure in `$PATH`, the manually installed one is searched first.
  So that when use `which go`, it will found the manually installed binary, instead of the one installed via `apt-get`.
  Thus could get the man page, while still able to use any desired version of golang.

Comment: @VonC But, I am not sure does other unix based systems have similar solution, e.g Centos / Mac.

Comment: That I don't know.